# Getting data from Google Cloud Compute Engine VM to Google Cloud Functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-compute-engine, dialogflow-es

Is there a way to create a Google cloud function that will access a compute engine vm and get some data like a text file in its disk/storage? i'm planning to create a cloud function on dialogflow that will get data from that VM from an input command.

Comment: I was checking the Compute Engine API but there is nothing like that, so your best option could be uploading that data to Cloud Storage and read it from there in Cloud Functions. If your data is generated periodically, you could always create a CRON job in the VM to use the [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) command to upload the files.

Comment: You could launch a mini-webserver on your VM that provides access to a directory. Using a 'secret key' that your VM and Cloud Functions use, you can protect that resource. A Python Flask or Node.js server would be easy to create. Then your Cloud Function can make a normal HTTP request to your VM to read files.

Comment: There is an answer for connecting the Compute Engine VM to Cloud Functions on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53108916/access-vm-instance-from-google-cloud-function-via-internal-ip-address . You can check it to see if this helps you.